# Trying to write custom aggregation function in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, aggregate, collect

Basically I'm re-writing some stuff I've already found around the internet and StackOverflow.

My aim is to write a custom aggregate function (in Oracle) as COLLECT is inadequate (I'm dealing with very large strings 4000 characters +), I don't have enough confidence in WM_CONCAT, and not even sure if it would be adequate.

It looks like a custom aggregate function is the best solution I have for building a JSON string of data from nested sub queries, building up the object, and so I need to be able to specify the delimiter between values - to put this into context.

The current ORACLE SQL I have is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE parms AS TABLE OF CLOB;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_agg_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
    total CLOB,
    l_delimiter CLOB,

    STATIC FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_TYPE )
        RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_TYPE ,
                           value IN parms )
        RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_TYPE,
                             RETURNValue OUT  CLOB,
                             flags IN NUMBER)
        RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_TYPE,
                         ctx2 IN string_agg_TYPE)
        RETURN NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE body string_agg_TYPE
IS
STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    sctx := string_agg_TYPE( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_TYPE,
                                   value IN parms )
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    IF (value.count = 2)
    THEN
        self.l_delimiter := value(2);
ELSE
  self.l_delimiter := ',';
    END IF;
    self.total := self.total || self.l_delimiter || value(1);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_TYPE,
                                     RETURNValue OUT CLOB,
                                     flags IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURNValue := ltrim(self.total,self.l_delimiter);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_TYPE,
                                 ctx2 IN string_agg_TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    self.total := self.total || ctx2.total;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

END;
```

When I try to compile the body definition, Oracle gives me the following error:

> Error(8,11): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STRING_AGG_TYPE'

So, anything obvious I've missed?

Thanks for the advice, should it be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object type `string_agg_TYPE` has two properties: `total` and `l_delimiter`, there is no reason for the latter to be of `CLOB` data type by the way, so, initializing the instance of  that object data type you should pass in two initializing values for those properties in the constructor:

```
sctx := string_agg_TYPE(NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I just found this out just now. Thanks anyway.